# Dots on a regular polygon.

Tags: geometry

I was thinking about math and came up with the following idea. It seems very obvious but I would like to see a concrete rigorous proof (albeit possibly a one-liner) for the following.

Consider a regular $n-$gon. Take one arbitrary point on each the sides of the $n-$gon (these points cannot be vertices). Prove that it is impossible to construct a concave $n-$gon using only the random points chosen.

My only progress has been that a triangle inscribed in a triangle can't be concave because there's not enough sides! I'm totally stuck.

It's really simple and obvious, but I'm trying to learn more about how to prove more abstract geometric problems. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: ok I fixed it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My only progress has been that a triangle inscribed in a triangle can't be convex because there's not enough sides!

I guess you mean it can't be concave, because it can definitely be convex. In fact, a triangle no matter how it is positioned is always convex.
What's more, randomness doesn't seem very relevant here: the problem is not probabilistic in nature, you're not asking for expected values nor providing a distribution,etc. I take it to mean any point can be chosen on any side except the vertices of the $n$-gon.
This conjecture seems to be false as the following counterexample shows (provided I understood it right):
[image]

EDIT: While your post itself didn't mention the polygon should be regular, it is included in the title. Your proposition is true in this specific case, and can be proved using analytic geometry.

Hint: Try to find the coordinates of the vertices of your n-gon using trigonometry, then use the following: If $M_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $M_2(x_2,y_2)$ are points in the plane, then $M(x,y)$ is a point of $[M_1,M_2]$ iff there exists $t\in [0,1]$ such that:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
tx_1+(1-t)x_2&=x \\
ty_1+(1-t)y_2 &= y
\end{array}
\right. $$
From there, you can describe your "random" polygon as a set of linear inequalities.
Similarly, $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is convex iff
$$\forall  ((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))\in A^2, \forall t \in [0,1],
(tx_1+(1-t)x_2, 
ty_1+(1-t)y_2) \in A $$
It is then sufficient to check that for any two points in your polygon satisfying the aforementioned inequalities, any point between the two (as described just above) also satisfies the inequality.

Comment: sorry yeah I meant to write concave I edited

Comment: I edited my post to take into account the special case where the polygon is regular.

Comment: Thanks Francois. Appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$-gon $A$ is inscribed in convex $n$-gon $B$ with one vertex on each edge of $B$ (those vertices joined together in cyclic order) then $A$ is convex.

To see that, think of $A$ as resulting from cutting off pieces of $B$ by removing vertices one at a time. Each cut preserves convexity.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That's an interesting way to think about it.